# Return blank string when element does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, lambda, asp.net-4.5

I am using the following query to convert XML to a struct. If an element does not exist how would I accommodate for it in the following query(ClntCde will always exist but there is a chance Title will not exist)

```
ClientTbl ClientData = clientNode.Select(x => new ClientTbl
    {        
        ClientCode = x.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ClntCde").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        //Title = x.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title").ToString(),
        //Title = x.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        //Title = x.Elements("Title").FirstOrDefault().Value,                                                            
    }
).First();
```

The XML:

```
<Client xmlns="http://www.website.co.za/namespace">
    <ClntCde>0000013</ClntCde>
    <Surname>Account Holder Surname</Surname>
    <Address>
         <Addr1>.</Addr1>
         <Addr2>.</Addr2>
         <Addr3>.</Addr3>
         <Addr4>.</Addr4>
         <PostCde>2000</PostCde>
    </Address>
    <ClntAccTyp>A</ClntAccTyp>
    <ElecInd>NO</ElecInd>
    <Lang>ENG</Lang>
</Client>
```

Comment: you should declare the namespace instead of using `LocalName`..That would reduce all the clutter from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Title = (String)x.Elements()
                 .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title")
                 .Single();
```

---

**OR**

delcare namepace

```
XNamespace ns="http://www.website.co.za/namespace";
```

and refer it

```
Title = (String)x.Element(ns+"Title")
```

Comment: This does not return the value or an empty string

Comment: @Moeri it would return value if element exits or would return null

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty("")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419.aspx):

```
ClientCode = x.Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ClntCde")
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("")
    .First(),
Title = x.Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title")
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("")
    .First(),
// ...
```

Note that the `...OrDefault` is redundant if you provide a default value yourself. It is safe to call `First` or `Single`(can still throw on multiple elements) since it can never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Title = x.Elements()
 .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title")
 .Select(e => e.Value)
 .FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ns = clientNode.GetDefaultNamespace();
ClientTbl ClientData = clientNode.Select(x => new ClientTbl
    {        
        ClientCode = (string)x.Element(ns + "ClntCde") ?? string.Empty,
        Title = (string)x.Element(ns + "Title") ?? string.Empty,
    }
).First();
```

Update 1: added default namespace

Update 2: added blank string if element does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Using this [XML Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) you can reference each element directly and give a default value if it doesn't exist like so:

```
ClientTbl ClientData = clientNode.Select(x => new ClientTbl
    {        
        ClientCode = x.Get("ClntCde", "defaultCode"),
        Title = x.Get("Title", "defaultTitle"),
        Addr1 = x.Get("Address/Addr1", "addr1 default"),
        // and/or
        Address = x.GetElement("Address") // Creates the Address node if doesn't exist
                   .Select(a => new
            {
                Addr1 = a.Get("Addr1", "addr1 default"),
                // etc
            })
    });
```

The default is type specific.  If your code is always numeric, you can use a numeric default and it will be that type.  `Get` also handles the namespace.

[Get has the syntax](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs#L257) of (in this case):

```
T Get<T>(string name, T defaultValue);
```